# Show Active User Icons — how to determine who is not online anymore (looking for NG or JS solution)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

In my Angular6 project I have a page of "collaborators". It is easy to display a collaborator but now I need to determine when the user is not on the page (or bounces) so i can remove the icon.

> I do not want to debug the code Im hoping i can find better logic. The code is less important at this point

## My Attempt

1. when any user updates `data` on the page update the `modified` timestamp.

   ```
   update_data() {
       db.object('dataRef').update({modified: Date.now()})
   }
   ```
2. Since the all users are subscribed to the `data` observable; on `data` change i  update all user objects with the same stamp (now I know who got the last update)

   ```
   // on data updated
   this.data.subscribe( res => {
       this.user.update({modified: Date.now()})
   });
   ```
3. Now that i know who got the data update; in the html I compare the user timestamps with the "data last modified" timestamp. if the timestamps dont match then i know that the user left the page.

   ```
   <div *ngIf="user.modified===data.modified">
       <!-- show this user icon because they recieved the last update -->
   </div>
   ```

*this works but it seems to complicated and the there is a delay between when the data was updated and when the user got the update - causing frontend challenges*

### Heres what worked for me

*based on **Mium's** answer*

component

```
    document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
        let visible = document.visibilityState==='visible';
        self.configsService.update_collab_visible(visible); // <= updates the db with true or false
    });
```

html

```
    <div *ngIf="user.visible">
        {{user.initial}}
    </div>
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, your database is on the backend or the frontend ? I will update my answer when you respond, but I assume your database is on the backend. So from there, how do you subscribe to a database in the backend ? you have a push server or a websocket ?

Comment: My database is api calls to firebase on frontend. But I have a nodebackend api if u have an idea

Comment: I posted a suggestion that I can update according to your feedback. Please check it and tell me if it does answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach to detect if user is active or not on your tab is to detect the visibility state.

**VisibilityChange API**:

> The Document.visibilityState read-only property returns the visibility
>   of the document, that is in which context this element is now visible.
>   It is useful to know if the document is in the background or an
>   invisible tab, or only loaded for pre-rendering.
>   more : 
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState

So first, for each user, you can detect presence more efficiently :

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", function() {
  console.log( document.visibilityState );
  // send notification to firebase
});
```

From this step, the only delay that you could experience will be strongly correlated to firebase. So you'd need to configure sync frequency, or if you really want to be fast, use a WebSocket connection for example.

Comment: Perfect. Im updating my question with the exactly code that worked